# Using Yii2 Access Rules behind Cloudflare to restrict actions by ips

Tags: yii2, iis-8, cloudflare

Enviroment: IIS 8 behind a Cloudflare Proxy

I'm using Yii2 Access Rules behind Cloudflare to restrict actions by IPS, which works fine when not using a Cloudflare proxy. I'd like to proxy through Cloudflare so I can use some of their features but if I do at present Yii see Cloudflare server addresses not the clients IP.

I believe the Yii2 Acces Rule restricting actions by IPS uses the `REMOTE_ADDR`  header, I would like to use the header `HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP`. Any ideas on how best to achieve this?

Am I best achieving this through Yii2 with an override or IIS itself or...?

Comment: I know I could achieve this with a function but I'd specificalyl like to use the Yii2 Access Rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure [`Request::$trustedHosts`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-request#$trustedHosts-detail) to IPs range of your proxy and [`Request::$ipHeaders`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-request#$ipHeaders-detail) to list of allowed headers which will be used to obtain use IP. For example in your web config:

```
'request' => [
    // ...
    'trustedHosts' => [
        '10.0.2.0/24' => [
            'HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP',
        ],
    ],
    'ipHeaders' => [
        'HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP',
    ],
],
```

Make sure that you configure IPs in `trustedHosts` correctly - all hosts which matches specified range will be able to fake user IP by sending `HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP` header.

You can read more about trusted proxies in [guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-requests#trusted-proxies).

Comment: This looks to be exactly what I wanted thanks @rob006 :) My Google-fu had failed me. I'll get reading up and give it a whirl

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm I have this working using the following in my web.config

`'request' => [
    // ...
    'trustedHosts' => [
        '103.21.244.0/22' => [
            'cf-connecting-ip',
        ],
        // ...
    ],
    'ipHeaders' => [
        'cf-connecting-ip',
    ],
],`

Cloudflare IPs can be found here: [Cloudflare IP Range](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/)